# Failed to compile because of incompatible cv-qualifiers

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have two template method

```
template <typename T, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
Ret apply(T* object, Ret(T::*method)(Args...), Args&& ...args) {
    return (object->*method)(std::forward(args)...);
};

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
Ret apply(T* object, Ret(T::*method)(Args...) const, Args&& ...args) {
    return (object->*method)(std::forward(args)...);
};
```

My purpose is apply member *method* of class **T** on these *args*

this is my test code:

```
int main() {
    using map_type = std::map<std::string, int>;
    map_type map;
    map.insert(std::make_pair("a", 1));
    std::cout << "Map size: " << apply(&map, &map_type::size) << std::endl; //this code work
    apply(&map, &map_type::insert, std::make_pair("a", 1)); //failed to compile

    return 0;
}
```

This is compiler error message:

```
    test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:61:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘apply(map_type*, <unresolved overloaded function type>, std::pair<const char*, int>)’
     apply(&map, &map_type::insert, std::make_pair("a", 1));
                                                          ^
test.cpp:11:5: note: candidate: template<class T, class Ret, class ... Args> Ret apply(T*, Ret (T::*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)
 Ret apply(T* object, Ret(T::*method)(Args...), Args&& ...args) {
     ^~~~~
test.cpp:11:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:61:58: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Ret’
     apply(&map, &map_type::insert, std::make_pair("a", 1));
```

Comment: I find about [8 versions of map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). Which one should the compiler use for `&map_type::insert`?

Answer (score 6):

[`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is an **overloaded** function. You cannot take its address unless you explicitly specify the overload you're interested about - how else would the compiler know?

The easiest way to solve your problem is to have `apply` accept an arbitrary *function object* and wrap your call to `insert` in a *generic lambda*.

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) apply(F f, Args&& ...args) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Usage:

```
::apply([&](auto&&... xs) -> decltype(auto)
{ 
    return map.insert(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...);
}, std::make_pair("a", 1));
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ioKfNKWGuSSQcrqV)

The additional syntactic boilerplate is unfortunately impossible to avoid. This might change in the future, see:

- [N3617](https://wg21.link/n3617) aimed to solve this issue by introducing a *"lift" operator*.
- [P0119](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0119r0.pdf) by A. Sutton solves the problem in a different way by allowing overload sets to basically generate the "wrapper lambda" for you when passed as arguments.

I'm not sure if *overloaded member functions* are supported in the above proposals though.

---

You can alternatively use your original solution by explicitly specifying the overload you're intersted in on the caller side:

```
::apply<map_type, std::pair<typename map_type::iterator, bool>,
        std::pair<const char* const, int>>(
    &map, &map_type::insert<std::pair<const char* const, int>>,
    std::make_pair("a", 1));
```

As you can see it's not very pretty. It can be probably improved with some better *template argument deduction*, but not by much.

Comment: I need *f* is a method of my class, how can I specify it. 
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: @PhạmVănThông: you can't pass `&std::map::insert` because you cannot take the address of an overloaded function or refer to it outside of a *function call expression*. The best you can do is pass a lambda/function object which forwards everything to `insert`. You can either capture the map instance or have it passed as an extra parameter to the lambda.